# BackgroundWorker randomly creating instances of objects in C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Pretty much I am trying to a make a stimulation of a larger app but as for now this will do to test things out so I tried to make it as dynamic(real world) as possible. So I have a class called Event which only has fields getters and setters methods, this is the class i want to make instances of objects from the backgroundworker. I have looked at some generic examples but they do not seem to be of great help because they are all based on a GUI app, mine is a console app.
Anyway as soon as the class Events is called from the main class(assuming the user provided the correct input) one event is created by default

```
class Events
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private Event newEvent;
    private List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
    private int listIndex = 0;

    public Events()
    {
        generateEvent(); //generate first event as soon as user initiates
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_doWork);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bw_doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int sleepTime = newEvent.random.Next(1000,5000); //events randomly created between 1 to 5 seconds
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        while (listIndex <= 15)
        {
            generateEvent();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
        }
    }

    private  void generateEvent()
    {
        newEvent = new Event();
        this.addEvent(newEvent);

    }
    private void addEvent(Event e){
        //check uniqueness and reassign value if necessary then add to the list
       e.setIdentifier(checkUniqueness(e.getIdentifier()));
       e.setX(checkUniqueness(e.getX()));
       e.setY(checkUniqueness(e.getY()));
       events.Add(newEvent);
       listIndex++;           
    }
    private int checkUniqueness(int num){
        foreach(Event eve in events){
            if ((num == eve.getIdentifier()) || //event identifier must be unique
                (num == eve.getX() && num == eve.getY())) //event x,y locations must hold one event
            {
                return checkUniqueness(num = newEvent.random.Next());//generate a new number for identifier
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
    public List<Event> getEvents()
    {
        return events;
    }
    public int getIndex()
    {
        return listIndex;
    }
}
```

however the backgroundworker class doesnt generate more events as the app is running which is what I need help with because I spent much time on it but I cant seem to get it done. Also when the events are created from the backgroundworker I want to report it(basically just add it to the List and call a method from the main class to update the number of events available) which again I dont know how to do because all the examples are based on GUIs.

Any help much appreciated unless backgroundWorker does not work on console applicatons?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to limit the number of elements to 15, is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right like I said a smaller scale stimulation and for now I just want to just get it to work

Comment: Di you see [this post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165759/using-console-writeline-in-a-backgroundworker-dowork-event) - If that is not you case, please also post the main class!

Comment: Btw: You don't need to invoke any write update reports to the console window. You ca use a simple call like this: `private static void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            displayAt(e.ProgressPercentage + "%", 11, 11);
        }  public static void displayAt(string s, int x, int y)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write(s);
        }` just make sure to prevent the console window from scrolling!

Comment: There is no difference in calling or getting results from a `BackgroundWorker` in GUI or Console apps. Can you post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What you posted doesn't compile, and names like `Event` and `getIdentifier` give us little to go on. Also, you set `bw.WorkerReportsProgress` but never call `bw.ReportProgress`; this makes me suspect your program ends before the first `Event` is generated.